# What permissions are required for Extended Events?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

My server administrator has created an extended event for me, but on my account I can't start the session and use it.

What permissions do I have to ask for in order to use extended events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Permissions**

Requires the `ALTER ANY EVENT SESSION` permission.

[ALTER EVENT SESSION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-event-session-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)